# Apache Spark with Hadoop distribution failing to run on Windows

Tags: windows, apache-spark, cygwin

I tried running spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6 distribution (and newer versions of Spark with same results) on Windows using Cygwin.
When trying to execute spark-shell script in the bin folder, I get below output:
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.spark.launcher.Main

I tried to set CLASSPATH to the location of lib/spark-assembly-1.5.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar but to no avail.

(FYI: I am able to run the same distribution fine on my MAC with no extra setup steps required)

Please assist in finding resolution for Cygwin execution on Windows.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into and solved a similar problem with cywin on Windows 10 and spark-1.6.0.

1. build with Maven (maybe you're past this step)

   mvn -DskipTests package
2. make sure JAVA_HOME is set to a JDK

   $ export JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60"

   $ ls "$JAVA_HOME"

bin        include         LICENSE      THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt ....

3. use the Windows batch file.  Launch from PowerShell or CommandPrompt if you have terminal problems with cygwin.

   $ chmod a+x bin/spark-shell.cmd

   $ ./bin/spark-shell.cmd

Comment: Works for me too on Spark 2.0, it is easy to forget bat files work in Cygwin/MINGW64 consoles as well.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to the problem was to move the Spark installation into a path that didn't have spaces in it. Under `Program Files` I got the above error, but moving it directly under `C:\` and running `spark-shell.bat` file cleared it up.